# How to check whether a set is a subspace of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, vectors

Three vector spaces are given, and each one has a set that is potentially the subspace of the vector space.

$$
(1) \quad V = \mathbb{R}^4 \quad W=\begin{Bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ -b \\ 2a+b \\ a \end{bmatrix}\space \bigg| \space a,b \in \mathbb{R}  \end{Bmatrix}
$$

$$
(2) \quad V = M_{3, 2}(\mathbb{R}) \quad W=\begin{Bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & y \\ 6b & |y| \\ 0 & x \end{bmatrix}\space \bigg| \space x, y \in \mathbb{R}  \end{Bmatrix}
$$

$$
(3) \quad V = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \quad W=\Big\{\space a - b(3-x)+c(x+5x^3) \space \bigg| \space a, b, c \in \mathbb{R} \space \Big\}
$$

I am pretty sure all three *W*'s are subspaces of corresponding *V*'s. However, my professor told me to check it once again, as it is unlikely that all are subspaces.

I checked the three points:

- If the Zero vector belongs to *W*.
- If *w1* and *w2* are vectors in *W*, their sum must also be in *W*.
- If *w* is a vector in *W* and *c* is some scalar in *V*, their product must also be in *W*.

However, this gave me a result I am not satisfied with.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The third point is false; it should be : if $w$ is a vector of $W$ and $\lambda$ a scalar, then $\lambda w$ is a vector of $W$.

Comment: The second case is not a subspace : indeed, taking two matrix $A_\pm$ with $y = \pm1$, then one has $A_+ + A_- \not\in W$, because the 2nd component is $1 + (-1) = 0$, but the 4th one is $|1| + |-1| = 2 \neq |0|$.

Comment: $\bullet$ "If *w1* and *w2* are vectors in *W*, their product must also be in *W*." - no, the product of vectors is not defined in general. Only the product of a vector with a scalar is always defined in a vector space.

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry, my bad, didn't notice I wrote it that way. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @Abezhiko, I am not sure I got the reason why the second case is incorrect. Why should $(x1, y1) + (x2, y2) = 0$ ? Isn't the rule about *w1*, and *w2* and their sum, instead of the parameters?

Comment: @AlexAramyan
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & \pm1 \\
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\in W 
\;\mathrm{but}\;
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
+ 
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & -1 \\
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 0 \\
   0 & 2 \\
   0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\not\in W 
$$
because the absolute value breaks down the linear structure.

Comment: @Abezhiko I now see what you mean. According to what you said $(0, y) + (0, -y) = (0, 0)$, but does this imply that $W(0, y) + W(0, -y)$ is also the zero-vector if *W* was a subspace of *V*?

Comment: @AlexAramyan   That's indeed the idea. However, be careful with the "column notation" without referring ot a basis; $(0,y)+(0,-y)$ has no meaning in the six-dimensional vector space $V$.

Comment: @Abezhiko got you, thanks :)